# How to connect to HTTPS proxy?

Tags: c#, .net, http, sockets

I'm trying to connect to HTTPS server through proxy using sockets. As far as I know when using HTTP proxy one should connect socket to it and then interact with it as it is the real server. With HTTP this approach works, but with HTTPS isn't. Why?

Here's simple program that connects to HTTPS server

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net.Security;

namespace SslTcpClient
{
    public class SslTcpClient
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string host = "encrypted.google.com";
            string proxy = "127.0.0.1";//host;
            int proxyPort = 8888;//443;

            // Connect socket
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(proxy, proxyPort);

            // Wrap in SSL stream
            SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream());
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(host);

            // Send request
            byte[] request = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format("GET https://{0}/  HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {0}\r\n\r\n", host));
            sslStream.Write(request);
            sslStream.Flush();

            // Read response
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            int bytes;
            do
            {
                bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                Console.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes));
            } while (bytes != 0);

            client.Close();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

It successfully connects when `proxy = host` and `proxyPort = 443`. But when I set them to 127.0.0.1:8888 (fiddler proxy on localhost) it doesn't work. Program hangs at `sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(host);` Why? Fiddler supports HTTPS (browsers are able to connect through it).

P.S. No, I can't use `HttpWebRequest` in my case.

Comment: It seems that I have to establish TCP tunnel through proxy first. It can be done using CONNECT method. But I still didn't manage to make it work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Managed to solve it myself. Here's the solution:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net.Security;

namespace SslTcpClient
{
    public class SslTcpClient
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string host = "encrypted.google.com";
            string proxy = "127.0.0.1";//host;
            int proxyPort = 8888;//443;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            int bytes;

            // Connect socket
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(proxy, proxyPort);
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            // Establish Tcp tunnel
            byte[] tunnelRequest = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format("CONNECT {0}:443  HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {0}\r\n\r\n", host));
            stream.Write(tunnelRequest , 0, tunnelRequest.Length);
            stream.Flush();

            // Read response to CONNECT request
            // There should be loop that reads multiple packets
            bytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            Console.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes));

            // Wrap in SSL stream
            SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(stream);
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(host);

            // Send request
            byte[] request = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format("GET https://{0}/  HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {0}\r\n\r\n", host));
            sslStream.Write(request, 0, request.Length);
            sslStream.Flush();

            // Read response
            do
            {
                bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                Console.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes));
            } while (bytes != 0);

            client.Close();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Poma, How to use this code as server? I want to download the page encrypted.google.com and send to client browser.