# Cannot connect to HTTPS proxy with HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, ssl, proxy

When I try to connect to HTTPS proxy with HttpWebRequest I'm getting the following error: `The ServicePointManager does not support proxies with the https scheme.` Is there a simple way to work around it? Here is the code sample that is failing:

```
namespace TestProxy
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var proxyUrl = "https://proxyhost:8888";
            var proxy = new WebProxy(proxyUrl, false);
            var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://targethost:80");
            request.Proxy = proxy; // NotSupportedException
        }
    }
}
```

It is possible to implement this with TcpClient (something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940893/how-to-connect-to-https-proxy)), but I'd like to use HttpWebRequest that does a lot of work for me. Otherwise I'll have to reinvent it with HTTPS support.