# How I can open https pages via socks on c#?

Tags: c#, sockets, https, proxy, socks

I'm using c# and I built socks5 client which uses socks5 server to get web pages. But these pages only on 80 port (HTTP). I wanna open pages which on 443 port (HTTPS). e.g.: https://google.com . If I'll just connect via socks5 on 443 -> google server rejects me. How can I do that?

PS: my client works via sockets, maybe I should use another way?

And sorry for my english.

Comment: See following posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940893/how-to-connect-to-https-proxy

Comment: @jdweng, thx for answer. It seems like a truth. I'll try it, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to @jdweng. The solution is:

we can use TcpClient or Sockets (doesn't matter) for connect to our socks server. e.g.:

```
create TcpClient using our socksIp/socksPort
get NetworkStream from our TcpClient.GetStream();

or use sockets

________
THEN:
________
send 0x05,0x01,0x00
receive 0x05, 0x00
send 0x05, 0x01, 0x00, 0x03, 0x0f, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x2e, 0x65, 0x78, 0x61, 0x6d, 0x70, 0x6c, 0x65 <- it's for www.example.com:443
receive 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, etc
if we used sockets -> create NetworkStream from our socket
create SslStream from our NetworkStream
in SslStream - authenticate as client with www.example.com
send our request like a "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.example.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"
receive while not eof
close stream/socket etc
```

Profit :)